# Can we execute/trigger selenium automation scripts through UFT

Tags: selenium, hp-uft

Using Webdriver, I have automated web based Application in eclipse and using QTP, I have automated Power Builder application(like desktop App).

Now both become depended module for me, from PB data's are flowing to web base application.

so, how can I achieve this. please someone provide me how to proceed with situation and give me some strategy to proceed

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same situation where powerbuilder application is integrating with the web application, below is the solution we have followed

We are using jenkins for executions, but this can be done without jenkins also.

We have one jenkins job which executes a UFT test first and then executes the selenium test if UFT test is successfull.

At the end of test execution UFT test will generate a file with the information required by selenium test and then jenkins will trigger selenium test, selenium test will read this file to gather any required information.

Results are interpreted in the following way

If UFT test fails then jenkins will not trigger the selenium test. If the whole jenkins job is executed successfully then integration is working, if the UFT part failed then Powerbuilder is having issue and if selenium part failed then web application is having issue.